# Cannot open JSON file from Fragment Activity - Android Studio

Tags: android, json, file, android-fragments

The problem is that I cannot open a .json file from the /assets folder.
[image]

The function I used:
[image]

The call:
String json = readJSONFile("planner.json");

I mention that the Activity extends Fragment.

THE ERROR:
***the is = manager.open(fileName); is null***

***Am I missing something?***

***EDIT:***

Logs:

[image]

Which comes from:
[image]

It's normal, due to the fact that the ***manager.open(fileName)*** returns **null**;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(readJSONFromAsset("planner.json"));
public String readJSONFromAsset(String fileName) {
    String json = null;
    try {
        InputStream is = getActivity().getAssets().open(fileName);
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return json;
}
```

Updated

You making a asset folder in wrong way in wrong path make it proper and it will work

Comment: Tried it with debugger.  It seems that the function you provided returns null.
It seems that the problem might not be about the actual code.

Comment: @sNow11 as show your screenshot possibly an asset folder creation problem. how you make asset folder? and where it's located

Comment: God, yes, the problem was the Asset folder. Both functions work. Thanks alot !

Comment: @sNow11 happy to helped you